# Bootstrap multiple dropdown menu with fixed position can not scroll the dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

try to add a navigation menu with bootstrap, it works well without fixed-top or sticky-top. however it can't scroll the dropdown menu when using fixed-top on a multiple level navbar, see demo below.

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  body {
    padding-top: 50px;
  }
</style>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NavBar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 1 <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-template text-center">
    <h1>Bootstrap NavBar</h1>
    <p class="lead text-info">NavBar with too many childs.</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

simply adding max-height and overflow-y to .dropdown-menu doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Giving overflow auto to the parent dropdown will work.

```
ul.dropdown-menu.multi-level {
max-height: 200px;
overflow-y: auto;}
```

Hope this is what you are trying to achieve